# Facebook like button liking too much

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm trying to do a Like button on all posts on "forumeiros" (free forum)
When I press "Like" on a post it like all next posts randomly, does not make any sense for me
Using the following code to generate buttons:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var url = new Array();
    var link = '';
    jQuery('.postbody .topic-title a[name]').each(function(index){
        link = "http://"+document.domain+jQuery(this).attr("href")+"/";
        link = link.replace('#', '/t');
        url.push(link);
    });
    jQuery('p.author').each(function(index){
        jQuery(this).after('<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href='+url[index]+'&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=55" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:24px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe><hr> ');
    });
});
```

Here two generated links:
`http%3A%2F%2Fgmbrdebug-t.forumeiros.com%2Ft2-teste-teste%2Ft2%2F`

`http%3A%2F%2Fgmbrdebug-t.forumeiros.com%2Ft2-teste-teste%2Ft3%2F`

Decoded: (Only showing href attribute set to facebook iframe)

`http://gmbrdebug-t.forumeiros.com/t2-teste-teste/t2/`

`http://gmbrdebug-t.forumeiros.com/t2-teste-teste/t3/`

So, why when I press "like" on first all following are "liked" too? they are different.

EDIT:
All url redirect to the same place, may be it?
    If yes, Theres no way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the generated links redirect to the same place then Facebook sees them as the same graph node. That's why liking one will like "all" of them - Facebook sees them as only one thing.

What you need is to have separate links for each post, and use those links for the Facebook like buttons.